# Fano plane drawings: embedding PG(2,2) into the real plane

Tags: discrete-geometry, projective-geometry, combinatorial-designs, incidence-geometry

By a drawing of the [Fano plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) I mean a system of seven simple curves and
seven points in the real plane such that

- every point lies on exactly three curves, and every curve contains
  exactly three points;
- there is a unique curve through every pair of points, and every two
  curves intersect in exactly one point;
- the curves do not intersect except in the seven points under
  consideration.

The familiar picture

[image: Traditional Fano plane] [(source)](http://math.haifa.ac.il/~seva/MathOverflow/Fano-1.jpg)

does not count as a drawing, since the last requirement is not satisfied:
there are two "illegal" intersections. In fact, this is easy to fix:

[image: Non-intersecting Fano plane] [(source)](http://math.haifa.ac.il/~seva/MathOverflow/Fano-2.jpg)

However, this drawing is degenerate in the sense that two of the curves
just "touch" each other, without crossing, at some point. And here,
eventually, my question goes:

> Is every drawing of the Fano plane degenerate?

(Although I can give a topological definition of degeneracy, it is a little technical and, may be, not the smartest possible one, so I prefer to suppress it here.)

Comment: Is it obvious that you can't draw the Fano plane with lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes, a line drawing is impossible, over ${\bf R}$ or any field $k$
not of characteristic $2$.
Let $A,B,C,O$ be non-collinear points of the Fano plane,
and $A',B',C'$ the intersections of $AO,BO,CO$ with $BC,CA,AB$ respectively.
By Ceva's theorem (actually proved by Al-Mutaman centuries earlier,
and extended algebraically to the case where $O$ is outside the triangle,
and indeed to arbitrary $k$), points $A',B',C'$ divide segments $BC,CA,AB$
in signed ratios whose product is $1$.  But by Menealus' theorem,
$A',B',C'$ are collinear **iff** that product is $-1$.  Since $1 \neq -1$
we're done.


Comment: ...and conversely, if $k$ does have characteristic $2$ then $A',B',C'$
are always collinear...

Comment: @Noam: I see, the basic idea is that (1) any line not passing thorough a vertex of a triangle intersects an even number of its edges, while (2) for any triangle $ABC$, and any point $O$ not on its boundary, the three lines $OA$, $OB$, and $OC$ intersect an odd number of the edges.

Comment: Actually I'm not using anything lke that (certainly not for an
arbitrary field).  Another way to say this is to choose projective
coordinates so $A$, $B$, and $C$ are at the unit vectors
$(1:0:0)$, $(0:1:0)$, and $(0:0:1)$, and then scale those coordinates
so that $O$, which must have all three coordinates nonzero (else it's
on one of the lines $AB$, $AC$, $BC$) is on $(1:1:1)$; then
$OA$ is the line $y=z$, so $A'=OA \cap BC$ is $(0:1:1)$,
and likewise $B = (1:0:1)$ and $C = (0:1:1)$.  Now calculate
that the determinant of $A,B,C$ is $2$, so $ABC$ are collinear
*iff* we're in characteristic 2.

Comment: Hm-m-m... I'd say you *do* use this - at least, for the real case. Let $A,B,C,O,A',B',C'$ be as in your comment. How many of the points $A',B',C'$ lie on the edges of the triangle $ABC$? An odd number, on the one hand (they are points of intersection of $OA$, $OB$, $OB$ with the edges), and an even number, on the other hand (they are points of intersection of the straight line through $A',B'$ and $C'$ with the edges) - a contradiction.

Comment: @Dustin G. Mixon Another way to see it is Sylvester–Gallai theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Does this one work?

[image][(source)](http://i44.tinypic.com/28jjns9.jpg)

Comment: Seems it does - very nice!

Answer (score 10):

Here is a bit more symmetric version of the picture in the accepted answer:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I always remember this diagram that seems impossible to find online. I have no source for it (except that I remember that it is/was engraved in the sidewalk near the Weber Building on the Colorado State University campus in Fort Collins, CO).

[image]

Does this one count as nondegenerate or is it still bad because of the outer circle only touching the red, blue and magenta curves?

Comment: Pretty but degenerate.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought because of the curves touching, but I wasn't sure if closing the loop made it okay.

Comment: Degenerate but beautiful!