# Incidence geometry and matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, matrices, real-algebraic-geometry, incidence-geometry

Supposing I have a $0/1$ or $\pm1$ matrix $A$ of size $m\times n$, is there a minimum $d$ (that works for every $m\times n$ $A$) such that there exists $m$ lines $r_1,\dots,r_m$, $n$ lines $s_1,\dots,s_n$ in $\Bbb R^d$ such that $r_i$ intersects $s_j$ iff there are some permutations $\Pi_1,\Pi_2$ such that $\widetilde{A}[i,j]=1$ where $\widetilde{A}=\Pi_1A\Pi_2$?

If so what is $d$ as function of $m,n,r$?

It is clear this is possible for special $A$ with $d=2$. Is it possible for every $A$ at some $d$?

Related: [When is a 0-1 matrix a one-intersection incidence matrix?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132516/when-is-a-0-1-matrix-a-one-intersection-incidence-matrix?rq=1)

Comment: What does "is there a minumum" mean?

Comment: Does $d$ fixed suffice?

Comment: It is still not clear --- do you want $d$ to be function of $A$ or not? Also, you need some obvious conditions on $A$ for this to be possible (think coplanarity). As it stands, the question is not clear, and shows no research effort. I downvote.

Comment: $d$, I think, should be a function of $m$,$n$ since it should work for every $m\times n$ matrix $A$.

Comment: The question might be better phrased without the word "minimum." Clearly if for each $A$ there is some $d$ so that this is achievable, then there is a minimum $d$ for fixed $m$ and $n$ because there are only finitely many such $A$. The question is whether for each $A$ there is some $d$.

Comment: @SamHopkins Can you quantify worst case $d$ as function of $m,n$?

Comment: @Boris I think that there is no coplanarity issue. Even if all of them intersect, they may be on a one-sheet hyperboloid, say. But perhaps, there might be some degree 2 surfaces in the question.

Comment: @MartinTancer I was wrong, and you are right. The question is clearer, I remove downvote. To elaborate on Martin's comment: The coplanarity arises in the non-bipartite problem (three lines pairwise intersect, then any two of them span the same plane). There will be a similar degree-$2$ constraint here because if we have a collection of lines that all intersect $l_1$ and $l_2$, then they lie on some quadratic. From that  Bezout should imply that in a large enough constant-sized complete bipartite graph, every $K_{2,2}$ subgraph spans the same quadric. So, for some $A$ there exist no $d$.

Comment: @BorisBukh Could you write your answer?

Comment: What does the new formulation with $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ change?  It seems to just give an equivalent question with a more confusing statement . . .

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I am just trying to state any symmetry in $A$ need not be relevant.

Answer (score 8):

As Will Sawin points out, this represents only a partial answer.

Theorem 5 of this paper

> Laison, Joshua D., and Yulan Qing. "Subspace intersection graphs." *Discrete Mathematics* 310, no. 23 (2010): 3413-3416.
>   [Journal link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X10002566)

proves that this graph

---

[image: Fig.1]

---

cannot be realized as the intersection graph of lines in $\mathbb{R}^d$ 
for any $d \ge 2$.
The corresponding incidence matrix is shown below,
using the ordering $(a,b,c,i,j,k)$.
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The logic of their proof is as follows (paraphrased from the paper).
Because $i$ and $j$ intersect (say at point $p$), they determine a plane $\pi$.
Since $a,b,c$ are mutually disjoint,
at most one could contain $p$.
Hence two of them are also contained in $\pi$,
as they intersect both $i$ and $j$; let these two be $a,b$.
Because $a,b$ are disjoint and lie in $\pi$, they must be parallel.
Now $k$ intersects both $a$ and $b$, so $k$ also lies in $\pi$.
But $k$ is disjoint from $i$ and $j$ (which cross in $\pi$),
which is impossible.

Comment: This requires identifying the rows and the columns, which the original question does not do.

Comment: @WillSawin: Thanks. I will mark it as only a partial answer. I was only addressing Sam Hopkins' comment: "The question is whether for each $A$ there is some $d$," and Boris Bukh's comment: "So, for some $A$ there exists no $d$."

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Nice reference.

Comment: @WillSawin what do you mean by 'identifying the rows and the columns'? what is wrong with this?

Comment: @Arul I mean the relation $r_i=s_i$.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the matrix
$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$
is not the incidence matrix for any distinct lines $r_1,\ldots,r_6$ and
$s_1,\ldots,s_6$ for any dimension $d$, over $\bf R$ or any other field,
and thus that there is no such $d(m,n)$ once $m,n \geq 6$.

The $5\times 5$ matrix $A_0$ formed by the first five rows and columns of $A$
is not enough: let $R,S$ be points on a plane $\Pi$;
let $r_1,r_2,r_3 \subset \Pi$ be lines containing $R$ but not $S$,
and $s_1,s_2,s_3 \subset \Pi$ lines containing $S$ but not $R$;
and then choose points $P,Q$ off $\Pi$ and collinear with neither $R$ not $S$,
and set
$$
r_4 = \overline{PS}, \quad
r_5 = \overline{QS}, \quad
s_4 = \overline{QR}, \quad
s_5 = \overline{PR}.
$$
But this seems to be the only way to realize $A_0$, and it does not extend to
$6+6$ lines with the intersections demanded by $A$ itself.

The key point is suggested by **Boris Bukh**'s comment:
of any three $r_i$, two must intersect.  Indeed if three pairwise skew lines
$l,l',l''$ have more than one transversal then they determine a quadric surface
$Q$ with two rulings, one of which includes $l,l',l''$ and the other consists
of all the transversals.  Then $s_1,s_2,s_3$ are in the other ruling,
and are thus pairwise skew.  Then $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are in the first ruling,
and it follows that all five $r_i$ are in one ruling and all five $s_j$
in the other.  Hence $r_i$ meets $s_j$ for every $i,j$ $-$ contradiction.

Likewise, of any three $s_j$, two must intersect.

On the other hand, if any three of the $r_i$ meet pairwise,
but not at the same point, then they span a plane $\Pi$ and $s_1,s_2,s_3$
must be on $\Pi$; and then they must also coincide, else every $r_i \subset \Pi$
and we soon reach a contradiction ($s_4$ meets $r_1,r_2,r_3$ but not $r_4$,
so $r_1,r_2,r_3$ meet at some point $R$ and $s_4$ contains $R$ but is not
in $\Pi$; likewise the same is true of $s_5$; but then $r_4,r_5$ also
go through $R$, which contradicts both the assumption at the start of
this paragraph and the $A_0$ condition).  Likewise if any three $r_i$
meet at a point $R$ but are not coplanar then $s_1,s_2,s_3$ go through $R$
and *are* coplanar, else every $r_i$ contains $R$ and again a contradiction
soon ensues.

From here it should be just a matter of hunting down which configurations
of skew/coincident/coplanar lines are possible among the $r_i$ and $s_j$
until only the one configuration described earlier survives…

Another candidate counterexample, with $m=n=7$, is a "double seven"
with $r_i \cap s_j = \emptyset$ *iff* $i=j$.  Even $(m,n)=(6,7)$
would suffice if the only way to get $(m,n)=(6,6)$ is the famous
"double six" configuration on a smooth cubic surface, on which
no two $r_i$ meet but the $r_i$ are not all on the same quadric,
and likewise for the $s_j$.

Comment: Just realized that I was thinking of the problem 
in projective space ${\bf RP}^d$, not ${\bf R}^d$.
Any ${\bf RP}^d$ construction can be put in ${\bf R}^d$
(just put the hyperplane at infinity somewhere random), but the converse
need not hold.  For example, $A$ is easily realized with $d=2$
by placing the $6+6$ lines at random except for $r_i \| s_i$ for $i=4,5,6$;
likewise the "double seven".  This can surely be fixed by adding a few more
lines (something like $r_i$ ($i=7,8,9$) meeting each of $s_1,s_2,s_3,s_{i-3}$
but not the other two), but it would take even more case analysis to prove...

Comment: So this does not work either?

Comment: Not as it stands, but it probably works with a few extra lines, so not $(6,6)$ but maybe $(6,9)$ or $(9,9)$.

Comment: did you ever get back to this problem again?